# Elliptic regularity on the Hypercube

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Assume

$$
Lu=f\quad \text{in } [0,1]^d\\
u=0 \quad\text{ on } \partial[0,1]^d
$$
for some strongly-elliptic operator $L$, and $f\in H^k$$, k\geq -1$. Do we have $u\in H^{k+2}$? I can only find the result for smooth domains.

I am pretty sure the answer is yes, for the Laplacian I can derive it myself. However, all proofs for general $L$ rely on "flattening the boundary", i.e. a $C^{k+2}$ boundary.

Comment: This reference seems to include a discussion on elliptic operators on torus https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783319146478-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1506284-p177198215

Comment: @Yuxin, if I understand Sections 11 and 16 of that reference correctly, regularity is shown for $-1\leq k\leq -1+\epsilon$ for general Lipschitz domains. Do you know if more is possible for the hypercube, i.e. can $k$ be chosen arbitrarily large?

Comment: @Bananach Did you end up finding an answer to this question?

Comment: @atzol I didn't